# How to override erb with liquid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid, templating-engine

I've added a theming directory to my app as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6082751/628859), using `prepend_view_path`. It works as expected. I can now add a view structure in my app under `app/themes/my_theme/views`

Now, I want to be able to override `erb` templates by dropping in a 
`.liquid` file, which will render right off the controller action.

For example, I want to override `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`:

```
<h1><%= t 'it_works' %></h1>
```

...with `app/themes/my_theme/views/pages/home.liquid`

```
<h1>It works with {{ "liquid" }}</h1>
```

I don't want to have to specify an array of view paths (upkeep would be awful), but just add `.liquid` as a layer to the templating engine. Maybe, however, have a blacklist of protected views that cannot be overridden (such as `app/views/admin/*`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a liquid template handler? Otherwise Rails won't know what you want to do with .liquid files. See this blog post: http://royvandermeij.com/blog/2011/09/21/create-a-liquid-handler-for-rails-3-dot-1/

For your second question: not using a theme for `app/views/admin/*` you should make sure you have an AdminController that does not `prepend_view_path`.

Comment: +1 for the "blacklist" solution. Looking into the handler blog post now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html#method-i-prepend_view_path) you can use `prepend_view_path`

Add the following to your ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :set_theme_path

def set_theme_path
  prepend_view_path "app/themes/#{current_theme}"
end
```

So Rails should then look for any views in your theme specific directory in preference to the default views in app/views/**/*

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But that only reads `erb` files. I want to use `liquid` instead of `erb`.

Comment: How are you naming your templates?  They probably need to be named foo.html.liquid

Comment: It's also a bit unfair to down vote an answer that is not wrong. As you admit you do what I posted. There could be a million things that are wrong with your environment that you have not disclosed or elaborated on in your question.

Comment: It was fair to downvote since I had stated in my question that I was already using prepend_view_path. The answer didn't seem like it was from someone who actually took the time to understand the question.