# How to render content from subfolder in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

I am using rails 4 from Suspenders and need to include content from a middleman-blog rack app from a subfolder in a view. In my app, I have the blog content in:

```
rails root > my_blog > source > index.html.erb.
```

I have created the view as:

```
rails root > app > views > welcomes > index.html.haml
```

The code in my view is:

```
%h1 Welcome

= render "my_blog/source/index.html.erb"
```

But when I access the page I get a Missing Partials error and the message says it only looked in the views folder.

How can I render content from a folder outside views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081603/how-can-i-add-a-view-path-to-railss-partial-rendering-lookup

Comment: I don't think thats a duplicate. That question is about files that are already under the views folder.

Comment: Can't you use the accepted answer to append_to or prepend_to the view path, based on ur requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial**

The problem is Rails is trying to call a [`partial`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), which is not what you're trying to call. A partial should have its name preceded with an `_underscore`, indicating to Rails that it's a partial, hence why you're receiving your error

The reason this is important is because although you're just calling `render`, you will actually call the partial too

[image]

--

**Convention**

One of the issues you have is that you'll be going *against* convention in several ways:

> - [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) dictates the "view" will be loaded per request (so Rails will expect it to just be present whenever you use it)
> - The "partials" functionality of your system needs to *add* to the views you're showing the users. This means you have to be sure you
>     have a view *already* showing on screen

This means you need to be certain if you're meant to be using a `partial` or other element in this part of your app. From the looks of it, whilst you *may* be doing something right, you need to be sure you're able to load the partial correctly:

```
<%= render "your/partial/path/_partial_name.html.erb %>
```

--

**View Path**

Further to your `view` path issue, although I've never encountered this issue directly, there is a function called [`append_view_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/append_view_path/class), which allows you to add another "path" to look at for your app:

```
#app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
Class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    append_view_path(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "app/themes/#{@current_theme}"))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the full path?

```
= render "#{Rails.root}/my_blog/source/index.html.haml"
```

Comment: I still get the same error:
Missing partial /Users/Documents/site/my_blog/source/_index.html.erb
Searched in:
  * "/Users/Documents/site/app/views"

Answer (score 1):

Try this is in your view file:

%h1 Welcome

```
= render :partial => "my_blog/source/index"
```

**Note: You must have _index.html.erb partial file in the above specified path.**

Also, try to change the name from _index.html.erb to _someothername.html.erb, because index.html.erb is usualy a view file for index action. You can avoid the unwanted confusions.

This may help you..!

Thanks!!

Added Lines (Edited):

Please change your file name from

```
rails root > my_blog > source > index.html.erb.
```

to

```
rails root > my_blog > source > _index.html.erb.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got the same error though.

Comment: Edited the answer. Try that. let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed _index.html.erb to _blog.html.erb. Then changed this line in my view: = render partial: "#{Rails.root}/msd_blog/source/blog". I got the same error. I wonder if this is a problem with referencing middleman?