# Rails render directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have app with few folders, but only one controller supported it

`folder_one` & `folder_two`, these folders should be rendered based on domain

if domain `one` should be rendered folder_one

How to do it?

main question is how to render folder based on request.

upd:

```
my app structure


accounts
 first_domain
  index.html.erb
second_domain
 index.html.erb
```

if request came from `first_domain.com` should be rendered `'accounts/index/first_domain'`

if request came from `'second_domain.com'` => `'accounts/index/second_domain'`

Comment: can you explain it more ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a view path to Rails's partial rendering lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081603/how-can-i-add-a-view-path-to-railss-partial-rendering-lookup)

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: @TusharPal updated

Comment: @MayurShah updated

Comment: Are you asking "how do I see what domain the request is from"? Use `request.domain`. I'm not sure what exactly your question is.

Comment: i think you can check the condition for domain by using request.domain and checking it with and render the template according to it

Answer (score 0):

[How can I add a view path to Rails's partial rendering lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081603/how-can-i-add-a-view-path-to-railss-partial-rendering-lookup)

Or:

one route, one action:
On controller:

```
def action_for_this_route
  if request.domain == 'first_domain'
    render "accounts/first_domain/index" and return
  elsif request.domain == 'second_domain'
    render "accounts/second_domain/index" and return
  end
end
```

Or with two different routes & actions on the controller
routes.rb

```
root 'index#first_domain', constraints: lambda { |request| request.domain == 'first_domain' }
root 'index#second_domain', constraints: lambda { |request| request.domain == 'second_domain' }
```

on controller:

```
def first_domain
  ...
end
def second_domain
  ...
end
```

But I would personally render always a single "index" and inside the index partial render either first or second domain.

Comment: is it possible to do within application_controller, but not in every controller?

Comment: @Sts what do you mean?